# Matplotlib plot line with empty markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting some data in this way:

```
plt.plot(x, data['Coherence'], color='b', marker='.', linestyle='solid', mfc='none', mec='b')
plt.xlabel("Number of Topics")
plt.ylabel("Coherence score")
plt.legend("coherence_values", loc='best')
plt.show()
```

And the output (correct) is:
[image: Text]

That is almost what I would like, but behind the markers, I can still see part of the line.
There is a way to get a result like this?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `markerfacecolor` parameter to "white" to obtain the desired result.

For instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot(np.random.randn(10), color='b', marker='.', linestyle='solid',  mfc='none', markersize=24, markerfacecolor='white')
```

Yields the following figure:

[image]

Comment: `mfc` is an alias for `markerfacecolor`. `mfc='none',` should be removed in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot(np.random.randn(10), 'b', marker = 'o', ms = 10, mfc = 'w')
```